# Python　バイナリデータがうまく読み込めない。

Tags: python, python3

バイナリデータがうまく読み込めずに困っています。

バイナリデータ

```
04725f06799b6081101c0103803e22782e08a5a2574fa2280f5054bfef8081c0810081809500b300
```

仮にこのデータをdata.binとして保存します。

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fp = open('C:\\data.bin','br')
    data = fp.read()
    print(data)
    fp.close()
```

元のバイナリデータを1バイトずつ扱いたいのですが、dataの中身は、以下のようになってしまいます。

```
b'\x04r_\x06y\x9b`\x81\x10\x1c\x01\x03\x80>"x.\x08\xa5\xa2WO\xa2(\x0fPT\xbf\xef\x80\x81\xc0\x81\x00\x81\x80\x95\x00\xb3\x00'
```

Cで記述した場合、

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    char str1[256];
    FILE *fp;
    errno_t err;

    err = fopen_s(&fp,"C:\\data.bin","r");

    if (err == 0) {
        int cnt = 0;
        while((a = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
            if (cnt < 256) {
                str1[cnt] = a;
                cnt++;
            }
            putchar(a);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

str1の内容は、バイトごとに読み取っていけば、もとのバイナリデータを復元できます。
※str1の大きさ256は適当に最大サイズにしていて、初期化をしていないため、代入していない配列には不定のキャラクタが入りますが気にしないでください。

Cのように、バイナリデータを文字データに代入すれば、文字列としては成り立ちませんが、元のデータは扱える・・・このようなことをPythonで実現するにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

print()関数の表示結果だからそのように見えるのであって、`data`を配列として考えれば1バイトづつ扱えるはずです。

例えばこんな感じで1バイトづつ16進数文字列と文字に対比して表示するとか、

```
for c in data:
    print(hex(c) + ' : ' + chr(c))
```

結果は

```
0x4 : 
0x72 : r
0x5f : _
0x6 : 
0x79 : y
0x9b : 
0x60 : `
0x81 : 
...後略
```

とか、特定の位置から内容を取得するなら、

```
a = data[0]
b = data[1]
c = data[2]
```

とかですね。

内容を書き換えたいなら、`bytearray`型に変換してから操作しましょう。

```
ba = bytearray(data)
ba[3] = 0x30
ba[4] = 0x31
ba[5] = 0x32
```

参考記事
[bytes, bytearray](http://python-remrin.hatenadiary.jp/entry/2017/05/23/130843)

Comment: 毎々ありがとうございます。bytearray型というのがあるのですね。助かりました。